# Cannot convert value of type 'Text' to closure result type '_'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm getting the following error:

`Cannot convert value of type 'Text' to closure result type '_'`

in my SwiftUI `Picker`:

```
struct Settings: View {
    @State var minAge = UserSettings().minAge
    @State var maxAge = UserSettings().maxAge
    @State var chosenSeeking = UserSettings.Seeking.both

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Picker", selection: $chosenSeeking) {
                ForEach(UserSettings.Seeking.AllCases, id: \.self) { chosen in
                    Text(String(chosen))
                }                
        }.padding(40)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to show each `case` of `enum Seeking` by passing in `UserSettings.Seeking.AllCases` to my `ForEach` above.

My Model is below:

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var minAge = 18.0
    @Published var maxAge = 99.0
    @Published var seeking = Seeking.both

    enum Seeking: Identifiable, CaseIterable {
        case male, female, both
        var id: Seeking {self}

    }
}
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `allCases` instead of `AllCases` and add `describing:` parameter in `String`'s `init` to fix your issue. Also, you don't need to give `id: \.self` since it's already identifiable.

```
struct Settings: View {
    @State var minAge = UserSettings().minAge
    @State var maxAge = UserSettings().maxAge
    @State var chosenSeeking = UserSettings.Seeking.both

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Picker", selection: $chosenSeeking) {
                ForEach(UserSettings.Seeking.allCases) { chosen in
                    Text(String(describing: chosen))
                }                
        }.padding(40)
    }
}
```

Comment: I won't steal your thunder again but the solve is to make the enum :String and use .rawValue

Comment: Did you try it? I did, you need to update 3 things to make it work in this way. Wouldn't work with `AllCases` even if the enum is `String` type and used `rawValue`.

Comment: Thanks this works. Why doesn't `AllCases` work though?

Comment: @Frankenstein I think you shouldn't be using `String(describing:)` unless it's just for debugging. You should use `.rawValue` instead (`Text("\(chosen.rawValue)")`).

Comment: @pawello2222 I thought about that too. But, OP  doesn't have a raw type for`Seeking`.